# When & How to use the connector in SharePoint Microsoft Flow

Tags: flow

[image]

Today I have seen new Connector in Flows

- PoliteMail
- Cloud Connect
- Marketo

I have tried to use those connectors, but not found any solution on google, could you please guide to use those connectors and the purpose of those connectors

Answer (score 0):

### [PoliteMail](https://politemail.com/)

Seems like an email analytics tool for Outlook.
The connector is described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/politemail/).

### Cloud Connect Studio

This integrates a trigger for Fuji Xerox Cloud Connect Studio solution
The connector is described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/appstudioapi/)

### [Marketo](https://www.marketo.com/)

Is  a marketing tool. The connector is described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/marketo/)